# Why do these CSS3 column-width elements add extra whitespace to their container?

Tags: css

I've created [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/sZpC2/) that demonstrates this weird behavior.
I've used the webkit prefixed version of the CSS rules and I've tested them only against Chrome 19 for Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra space in the columns is from some of the styles you have specified (e.g. `width:100000px;`). To fix, use the following CSS ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/sZpC2/4/)):

```css
#container {
 height: 250px;
 -webkit-columns: 15em;
 -moz-columns: 15em;
 -ms-columns: 15em;
 -o-columns: 15em;
 columns: 15em;
}
#container article {
 vertical-align: top;
 display: inline;
}
#container article img {
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: your solution answer my question but unfortunately for me it doesn't answer the root issue that caused it ;-) the fact is the I need to chain together multiple *independent* lists, but I think this issue requires an additional question :-) thanks anyway for the previous responses!

Comment: @olistik, I'm fairly confident the *exact* rendering comes down to a bug in Chrome, but the basic idea is the width of the `article` (which was `inline-block`) will be the same as the width of `#container`, and the maximum width is limited to `4177px` (Why? I have no idea). So, any width for `#container` over `4177px` results in an article with that width. Anything less results in a width equal to `#container`. That's why the three `articles` didn't take up the full width of `#container`.

Comment: @olistik, oh, read your comment before you edited. Ping me when you ask it; I may be able to help.