# Webkit CSS3 column adds an extra padding to its container.

Tags: html, css, webkit, multiple-columns

I've created a CSS3 multi column layout for image gallery which looks nice on Firefox.

### HTML :

```
<section id="featured">
<article>
    <img src="http://sheepy.me/incoming/images/posts/blog/thumb_tim-burton-pokemans.png" />
</article>
<article>
    <img src="http://sheepy.me/incoming/images/posts/blog/thumb_hem-tourniquet.png" />
</article>
<article>
    <img src="http://sheepy.me/incoming/images/posts/blog/thumb_hem-tourniquet.png" />
</article>
<article>
    <img src="http://sheepy.me/incoming/images/posts/blog/thumb_tim-burton-pokemans.png" />
</article>
<article>
    <img src="http://sheepy.me/incoming/images/posts/blog/thumb_tim-burton-pokemans.png" />
</article>
```

css :

```
#featured {
    width: 730px;
    padding: 20px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-fill: balance;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-fill: balance;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 10px;
    column-fill: balance;
    background: #7d90a5;
}

article {
    width: 300px;
    display: block;
    background: #344252;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 335px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

article img{
    width: 335px;
    display: block;
}
```

The problem is, when I am using Chrome browser to open it up, it adds extra space at the bottom of the `<section>` which I have no idea to fix it. 
I've search the web and found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363689/why-do-these-css3-column-width-elements-add-extra-whitespace-to-their-container) but I am not sure if it's the same issue.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SdtP5/3/) link and try open using both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I don't know of a solution, but the large space goes away when you remove `-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;` from the `article` styling. This however leaves a seemingly empty yet non-existent article at the top of the right column.

Comment: Yeah that would broke the top right picture. I'm still looking for a pure css solution...

Answer (score 9):

Try this CSS

```
#featured 
{
    overflow:hidden;        
}
```

Comment: For me this worked .. Currently my best bet is that the container gets an approximation of the height that the element would get without the use of columns. But perhaps there is someone who could explain the behaviour better (or point to an explanation somewhere).

Comment: This is the fix for people who do not have padding issues.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. You saved me a huge headache. Thanks

Comment: Wow, so much better than converting my block elements into inline-block.

Answer (score 8):

A quick fix, targeting only -webkit- browsers

```css
#featured {
    -webkit-margin-after: -110px;
}
```

Also, when using columns, I find that displaying the elements inside as inline-blocks, helps prevent them from breaking apart (in your case)

```css
article {
     display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: display: inline-block; helps me to avoid extra margin at the top of a new column. Thank you!

Comment: display: inline-block; made columns finally usable. I can hardly believe it is that simple, thanks!

Comment: display: inline-block; Worked for me too. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Alternative to using { display: inline-block }

```
article {
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
          page-break-inside: avoid;
               break-inside: avoid;
}
```

sourced from: [Similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921852/css3-columns-cutting-off-lis), [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/break-inside/)

Answer (score 3):

You use margin-bottom in each article 20px, 
and padding the container in 20px to,

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ariel_ma/SdtP5/14/)

```
#featured {
   padding: 20px 20px 0 20px
 ...}
```

Comment: Nice way to solve this issue, and I think this is a correct answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, try...

```
#featured{
   padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
   ...
}
```

and

```
#article{
   display: inline-block;
   ...
}
```

Comment: `padding: 20px 0 20px;` would suffice also.

Answer (score 1):

It is just white-space!

```
section {font-size:0}
article {font-size: 1rem} /* if necessery */
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use with a property `column-break-inside: avoid;` any `margin` or `padding`, `border` just `margin-bottom`, i think this best solution for this problem. http://jsfiddle.net/SdtP5/3

Answer (score 0):

You did `padding: 10px;` that also adds padding to the bottom. Use this to remove padding at bottom:

```
padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
```

Answer (score -1):

If i'm understanding the question right,
you might try adding `padding:0` or even something such as `padding:-10px;` or similar to the containter