# Unwanted bottom margin in photo grid Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, margin

The problem is pretty simple but after surfing the web for hours I still cant solve it. I have a div with nested image grid. Everything works fine in chrome but not in IE. For some random reason it adds bottom margin. Which I cant get rid of. I tried floating, clearfix, and a lot of other things but it just wont react.

[Colorized image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSsmD.jpg)

```
  <section class="body">
   <div class="bodyContainer" id="photos">
    <img src="images/Ernst Neizvestny.jpg" />
    <img src="images/Erik Boulatov.jpg" />
    <img src="images/Eugene Yelchin.jpg" />
    <img src="images/GeniaChef.jpg" />
    <img src="images/Ilya Kabakov.jpg" />
    <img src="images/KomarAndMelamid.jpg" />
    <img src="images/Kosolapov-Alexander.jpg" />
    <img src="images/Oleg Tselkov.jpg" />
    <img src="images/Lev Meshberg.jpg" />
    <img src="images/Leonid Sokov.jpg" />
    <img src="images/Vassiliev-Oleg.jpg" />
    <img src="images/Rapoport.jpg" />
    <img src="images/Vladimir Nemukhin.jpg" />
    </div>
   </section>
```

CSS:

```
    #photos {
    /* Prevent vertical gaps */
    line-height: 0;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-gap: 0px;
    column-count: 4;
    column-gap: 0px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    background-color: red;

}
#photos img {
    /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 1%;
    padding:0;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color:green;
}
/* CSS Document */
 @media (max-width: 1000px) {
    #photos {
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    #photos {
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    #photos {
        -moz-column-count: 1;
        -webkit-column-count: 1;
        column-count: 1;
    }
}

   .body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    clear:both;
}
.bodyContainer {
    width:80%;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 641px) {

    .body {
        clear: both;
        min-height: 100px;
    }
    .bodyContainer {
        clear: both;
        min-height: 100px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
    }
```

Comment: Without seeing more code, we can only guess the solution. `.bodyContainer{height:auto;}` could be the issue. That is just an image you show us, so we don't know. You may consider colorizing `.bodyContainer`, so we can see if there are more Elements we should know about... or better yet, include more code.

Comment: Which versions of IE are you having issues with?

Comment: @PHPglue I have added colorized print screen and all the code that is related to those 2 div containers.

Comment: @partypete25 IE 11 as well as Microsoft Edge

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webkit CSS3 column adds an extra padding to its container.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767824/webkit-css3-column-adds-an-extra-padding-to-its-container)

Comment: I've been messing wit this and searched google and found a [duplicate on SO dating 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767824/webkit-css3-column-adds-an-extra-padding-to-its-container) without any success. Unless this is mission criticle, I'd stop seaching and head to a new problem as apparently vendors are not interested to solve it.

Comment: @user3183915 I can't reproduce the problem you have . I've recreated it both locally and on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/partypete25/jag9ezvv/embedded/result/ using the html and css from your question. I know the images are different but i wouldn't think that should make a difference. You might have to update your question and share more of your html/css.

Answer (score 0):

Well after significant poking around I somewhat solved it. First issue was the 2% margin all around. Just replaced it with 2% to bottom and left of the image. Second, since the images were all different sizes it added padding to the image itself (This is IE issue only) so I removed the padding. Third, I cropped images so they would all stick to a strict proportion. Perhaps an easy way out, but it works in my case. Thank you everyone who tried to help.

Cheers!