# How to fix a white gap after Bootstrap 4 Cards (CSS3 multi-columns bug)(Chrome IE )?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have very annoying bug on Chrome and IE (On Fire Fox it looks fine). I am not really sure what element or elements are doing this.

About the bug:  If you scroll down, you can see where the Bootstrap cards end a big white gap between them and the footer.

[image]

URL where the bug is: I have to remove my URL (Stackoverflow rules...sorry guys)

I have been using Google Chrome Inspect to try to find where the problem is but I did not have luck. That is the reason why I am asking here because I can see where the problem is.

The only clues I have are:
-   The bug is not in any JS file or in any extern css file, I think there is something in my CSS is doing this. 
-   It is not the position:relative or the overflow:hidden form the class dtl24, because I have tried to delete them and updated my CSS without them and the bug was still there.

Also, I would like to apologize to you. I have tried to create a snippet with the code but without the images, the bug not appreciable.

Do you know where is the bug and how I could fix it please?

Thanks

Comment: Look fine in Chrome,there is not  gaps. Might be cache issue,try clearing cache.

Comment: I did that. Also I have tried it on different PCs and I can see it.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767824/webkit-css3-column-adds-an-extra-padding-to-its-container) with CSS3 multi-columns that can cause a gap at the bottom. There are only workarounds for this issue, and depend on the specific layout.

You can try using...

```
.card-columns .card {
    display: flex;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
}
```

But, you may need to ultimately use a large negative margin at the bottom of the container for Chrome / Webkit browsers:

```
.card-columns {
   -webkit-margin-after: -300px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: It nice to know that. Thank you. I will try it as soon as I can. I let you know if it works.

Comment: It works. I didn't need to use the second code.  With the first one is enought. Thank you very much. I didn't know anything about this bug.

Comment: It's weird that they haven't fixed this after such a long time. Do you know of an official bug report if any on Webkit/Chrome regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because of this styling.

```
column-gap: 1.25rem;
```

Comment: Oh dear, but I need it in order to have space between the columns. Let me play whit it. Thanks

Comment: You can use the three `div` which you have to have gaps like applying `padding-bottom` and `padding-right`. You need not apply on the whole card.